# How can I select a default interactive console in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Using PyDev 2.7.1 in Eclipse 3.7.2, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new interactive console, I get a dialog asking me what type of console I'd like to start ("Console for currently active editor", consoles for Python, Jython, Iron Python etc.).

Now this selection dialog has no default entry and keyboard selection doesn't work, meaning that I have to use my mouse every time I need a new console, which is kind of tedious.

I've checked **Preferences** → **PyPev** → **Interactive Console**, but found no interesting options there.

Is there any possibility to define a default interactive console type so that I just have to hit Return when the dialog pops up or, even better, skip this question altogether?

Comment: I would like to know this too, its also a problem using 'f2'